# How to test equivalence of ranges

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

One of my unittests checks to see if a range is set up correctly after reading a log file, and I'd like to just test `var == range(0,10)`.  However, `range(0,1) == range(0,1)` evaluates to `False` in Python 3.

Is there a straightforward way to test the equivalence of ranges in Python 3?

Comment: Why are you comparing two ranges?

Comment: My unittest just asserts that the range was correctly constructed.  In the program, instead of storing min & max acceptable values, I store the range then test if val in range.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python3, `range` returns an iterable of type `range`. Two `range`s are equal if and only if they are identical (i.e. share the same `id`.) To test equality of its contents, convert the `range` to a `list`:

```
list(range(0,1)) == list(range(0,1))
```

This works fine for short ranges. For very long ranges, [Charles G Waldman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740796/how-to-test-equivalence-of-ranges/7741846#7741846) is better.

Comment: @oneporter:  Be warned that this consumes the iterator and you will not be able to reconsume it later.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Since `range` objects are iterables and not iterators, they can't be "consumed".  [You can iterate over them multiple times.](http://ideone.com/RGvxv)

Answer (score 6):

The first proposed solution - use "list" to turn the ranges into lists - is ineffecient, since it will first turn the range objects into lists (potentially consuming a lot of memory, if the ranges are large), then compare each element.   Consider e.g. a = range(1000000),
the "range" object itself is tiny but if you coerce it to a list it becomes huge.  Then you have to compare one million elements.

Answer (2) is even less efficient, since the assertItemsEqual is not only going to instantiate the lists, it is going to sort them as well, before doing the elementwise comparison.

Instead, since you know the objects are ranges, they are equal when their strides, start and end values are equal.  E.g.

`ranges_equal =  len(a)==len(b) and (len(a)==0 or a[0]==b[0] and a[-1]==b[-1])`

Comment: This will not work if the ranges step.  For example range(1,20,2) and range(1,20) would be equivalent.

Comment: Good point krs1.  I think that my approach could be fixed by also comparing the len() of the ranges .... ranges_equal = (len(a)==len(b) and a[0]==b[0] and a[-1]==b[-1])

Comment: Or, if avoid problems with empty ranges:  `ranges_equal = len(a)==len(b)==0 or len(a)==len(b) and a[0]==b[0] and a[-1]==b[-1]`

Comment: I'm not so sure I think `range(0,0)` is necessarily equal to `range(100,100)`, even if both ranges are empty.  I guess It depends on what you are doing with them...

Comment: Well, to me they are both just different ways of spelling "empty".  But if this matters, note that all of the other suggestions also fail to distinguish these cases.  If this mattered, you could do `ranges_equal = str(a)==str(b)`

Answer (score 1):

Try `assertItemsEqual`, (in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual)):

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_mytest(self):
        a = (0,1,2,3,4)
        self.assertItemsEqual(a, range(0,4))
```

Comment: Note that assertItemsEqual is not available in py3, which is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

`ranges_equal = str(a)==str(b)`

The string representation indicates the start, end and step of ranges.

This question makes me think that perhaps Python should provide a way to get these attributes from the range object itself!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the necropost. But here's the simple way.

Python implements a way to test if ranges are equal:

```
range(1, 999, 100) == range(1, 1000, 100)
```

returns `True` as the ranges have the same elements (1, 101, ... , 901)